# maven assembly how to add a zip flie from nexus repository to the build

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am trying to include a zip file from nexus repository to my project during packaging using the maven assembly plugin.  This zip file has YAJSW and other custom scripts.  The maven assembly can build a tar.gz package now, but how do I include a zip file from nexus repository.  There is a pom for that zip file.  Should I just include that as dependency?  Is this the correct plugin or should I use another plugin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the dependency of the zip file like the following:

The following is an example for archive which has been created by maven-assembly-plugin:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>the.group.id</groupId>
  <artifactId>the-artifactid</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <type>tar.gz</type>
  <cassifier>bin-unix</classifier>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>the.group.id</groupId>
  <artifactId>the-artifactid</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <type>zip</type>
  <cassifier>bin</classifier>
</dependency>
```

The classifier in those cases is comming from the assembly-decscriptor-id in the project which creates the archive. Apart from that it is important to define the type.

Comment: Thanks.  I was using copy-scripts with maven-dependency plugin. But this is a much better solution.  Along with the dependency, I am using unpack (maven-dependency) in prepare-package stage to unzip the files now.

Answer (score 0):

Add a dependency to the zip with the respective GAV (group/artifactId/version).

(Without seeing your pom.xml it's a bit hard to say more).